# How to randomly load an image with picasso

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, picasso

I want to know if it's possible to load a random picked image from an array with picasso?

This is the code i use to load my album art, but what i want to achieve is that when there is no album art found, i want to display a random image and not the same image.

```
private void loadAlbumArt(){

    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, songList.get(songIndex).getAlbumID());

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(albumArtUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.no_album)
            .error(R.drawable.no_album)
            .noFade()
            .resize(500, 0)
            .into(mAlbumArt);

}
```

Thanks in advance,

Vince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3,
            R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6};

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(myImageList.length);

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(albumArtUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.no_album)
            .error(myImageList[randomNumber])
            .noFade()
            .resize(500, 0)
            .into(mAlbumArt);
```

Comment: There is an even simpler solution: simply use Arrays.shuffle() to put the array in a random order. Then you dont need to worry about generating a Random instance or array length. Shuffle it, access the first element, done.

Comment: I have to do something like this : `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(myImageList))`

Comment: Or that, sorry, sometimes memory is cheating on me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can this code

**Check if album art is available or not**  , so the method looks like this

```
 private void loadAlbumArt() {

        Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, songList.get(songIndex).getAlbumID());
        if (!albumArtUri.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(albumArtUri)
                    .noFade()
                    .resize(500, 0)
                    .into(mAlbumArt);
        } else {
            int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3,
                    R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6};

            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.nextInt(myImageList.length);

            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(myImageList[randomNumber])
                    .noFade()
                    .resize(500, 0)
                    .into(mAlbumArt);
        }
    }
```

now you can display random image when the album art is not available

Answer (score 0):

```
private void loadAlbumArt(){

    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, songList.get(new Random().nextInt(songList.size())).getAlbumID());

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(albumArtUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.no_album)
            .error(R.drawable.no_album)
            .noFade()
            .resize(500, 0)
            .into(mAlbumArt);

}
```